# Increasing MaximumErrorCount for Data Export in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, data-export

I have looked at countless other stack posts and random blogs but cannot find where this setting is located.

I have a database on SQL Server 2017 that I want to change the collation on. [Because we're using schema-bound objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#changing-the-database-collation) we cannot just do an `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase COLLATE MyCollation;` so we need something else. I tried to follow [the guide on this blog post](http://www.macaalay.com/2011/12/19/the-easy-way-of-changing-collation-of-all-database-objects-in-sql-server/) suggesting a backup of keys and indices, drop them, recreate database, import the keys and indices, but as I don't understand enough about [cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and where the `@table` variable is coming from I moved on from that approach.

My current thinking is that if I can just export the necessary data from the necessary tables, create a new database, and then re-import the data to the new database with the correct collation I should be set. I'm using SSMS and going with Tasks > Export Data... to get the data out from the database with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as both Source and Destination. When this wizard runs, the first run only gives Status = Success. The second one gives Warnings on Validation. The third run throws Error on Validation:

```
Warning 0x80049304: Data Flow Task 1: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; 
data flow performance counters are not available.  
To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

[image]

The thing is, I'm logged in with the SA account. The Copying Rows completes on warnings saying:

```
Warning 0x80019002: Data Flow Task 3: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. 
This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

The target/destination database only contains some of the tables, presumably because it hit the maximumerrorcount before it could finish.

My question is, where can I increase the MaximumErrorCount?

**EDIT:** [It seems that I'm not the only one having similar issues with data export/import in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687903/sql-server-management-studio-import-quietly-ignoring-99-9-of-data)

Comment: The wizard creates an SSIS package. You can save it and edit it.

Comment: I tried to save it as a package without running it and edit the contents as a text-file. I changed the row DTS:MaxErrorCount="0" to DTS:MaxErrorCount="2147483647" (max Int32) but it still fails on the first error because it seems to not be change: "Method succeeded but number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1)". Am I going about it incorrectly when trying to change the MaximumErrorCount?

Comment: So I tried to edit the dtsx package in Visual Studio with SQL Server Data Tools as well as the SQL Server Integration Services Projects, then changing the MaximumErrorCount to a ridiculously high number, and saving the dtsx filet as a new file. Even doing this makes the Execute Package Utility throw the "reached maximum (1) errors" error.